# What are these resistors for?

Tags: mosfet, poe

I am looking at implementing a MOSFET Bridge Rectifier circuit. I am trying understand why there is a difference in the basic application circuit and layout from the app note. The layout image below has resistors while the basic application circuit does not.

The [app note](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND6234-D.PDF) shows a basic application circuit here:

[image]

But then shows a layout with resistors 8 total as seen here:

[image]

Does anyone know what the purpose of those resistors could be?

Comment: are you sure that they are resistors?

Comment: If the IC is orientated the same way as the diagram on page 4 (pin 1 to bottom right) then those resistors are on the gates of the MOSFETs, so they could just simply be pull-ups or pull-downs on the gates

Answer (score 1):

They look like zero ohm jumpers to me.  They'd be used change the setup of the circuit on those evaluation boards.